# Game High Scores with names

Tags: c#, winforms, streamreader, streamwriter

How exactly would someone go about making high score reading code, that includes the name in Windows Form in C#?
For example: Steve 600
I can get the numbers part with StreamReader/Streamwriter, but I cannot figure out a way to include the name. Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you have? an own made game in winforms? if so, make a popup for the user to insert their name and put it in a label above higscore

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to write each value on its own line, so you might have:

> Steve
>   600
>   George
>   500
>   Peter
>   200

Then in your loop you'd just read one line, which would be the name, then read another line, and parse it into an `int`. Then if you're not at the end of the file, do the same again.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate them with special delimiter like **$** Also don't Allow user to use your delimiter in name, So you will have:

**Steve$600**

Then you can use [`StreamReader.ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) method to get this line string and then use `string.Split` to split on delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to load scores from another game with a fixed format?

if the format is NAME SCORE we search for the last space, because the name probably also can contain spaces and split the string in name and score part.

```
    private List<Score> ReadScores(string filename) {
        List<Score> scores = new List<Score>();

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(filename)) {
            string line = "";
            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((line = sr.ReadLine()))) {
                int lastspace = line.LastIndexOf(' ');
                string name = line.Substring(0, lastspace);
                string pointstring = line.Substring(lastspace + 1, line.Length - lastspace - 1);

                int points = 0;
                if (!int.TryParse(pointstring, out points))
                    throw new Exception("Wrong format");

                scores.Add(new Score(name, points);

            }
        }

        return scores;
    }

    class Score {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Points { get; set; }

        public Score(string name, int points) {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Points = points;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to not use StreamReader or StreamWriter then you could use an input box for the user to input their own name. eg:

```
string sName;


            //asks user to input their name before the game begins
            sName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please enter your name:", "What is Your Name?", "");
            //if no name is entered, they are asked again

                   while (sName == "")
                    {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter your name.");
                    sName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please enter your name:", "What is Your Name?", "");
                     }
```

As well as declaring the variable, you would also need to include

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
```

at the top of your page. And additionally you will need to add a reference to the page. On the right hand side in the Solution Explorer, if you right click on References, the Add Reference, in .NET you will find 'Microsoft.VisualBasic'

You can put the actual Inpuxbox code anywhere in your code and you can re-use and edit it with great ease.